# I can't find the good use of a firebase remove object

Tags: javascript, database, firebase

I tried to use the new remove() function that is written in the Firebase Realtime Database documentation, but I can't really figure out how to actually remove the data. I get an error saying userRef.remove() is not a function. But I have no idea how to actually use it.

This is the code that gives me that message:

```
document.getElementById("yes-delete").addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
                  const userRef= ref(db, 'users/' + user.uid);
                  userRef.remove();
              });
```

This is the error message I'm getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: userRef.remove is not a function
> at HTMLButtonElement. ((index):209)

This is what they write on Firebase documentation:

> **Delete data**
>
> The simplest way to delete data is to call remove() on a reference to
> the location of that data.

Answer (score 0):

It was just remove(userRef);
My apologies